# keras: trainable_weight issue

Tags: deep-learning, keras, convolution, keras-layer

In one particular application, I need to train only bias of the convolutional operation. Therefore I removed W parameter from trainable_weight. that looks like this:

```
self.trainable_weights = [ self.b]
```

I save model at 0 epoch and after 200 epoch and I found that W is somehow able to learn. Do not know what is going on. When I saw model.summary() it showing the correct number of learning parameters. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: This is not possible using Keras as far as I know. This is somewhat similar to the issue: [how to freeze specific weights in a layer](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3217). You will have to edit Theano. Dive into the source code of `fit` and see the update rule for parameters. You will have to switch off the update of weights. I will try to attempt an answer sometime later if you cannot get it.

Comment: I looked into `fit` function of _keras_ but unable to figure it out, which parameters are used to differentiate the loss function.

Comment: Please keep in mind that keras is a wrapper, if you want to edit something about the actual computation you will probably have to dive into the source code of your backend  as mentionned above.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have implemented in **theano** and it easily doable in **lasagne** via doing `net.params[net.W].remove('trainable')`. But **keras** is new for me and I find it hard to implement there.